# How to implement Multi Tenancy architecture using Node and Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multi-tenant

I am working on a SaaS application in which every client will have their own database. I am distinguishing the clients via their DNS.

So, what I learned after googling a while is that I will create a master DB which will have respective username and password for respective client. I will create new connections at the runtime.

I came across different strategies but I can't even find a single proper implementation for the same using Nodejs and Mongoose.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you described?  In general multitenancy isn't a language specific problem, and the solutions are pretty language agnostic.

Comment: @Paul I having issues with implementing the solution. For eg -  I am able to create new connections according to the DNS but there are certain cases like if there are 2 people trying to log in into my app and they belong to same organisation i.e their DNS is same then I'd like not to create 2 different connections. Only 1 connection should suffice for both. I am new to this concepts so was looking for an already baked code so I get going.